# datasource not binding to kendo grid

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to get the kendo-grid on my html screen. It does not shows any error but does not shows the outut as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <h1>Customer list</h1>

    <div ng-controller="CustomerController">
        <!--<kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions">

        </kendo-grid>-->

        <div ng-controller="CustomerController" id="myKendoDemos" kendo-grid k-data-source="gridData" k-columns="gridColumns"></div>
    </div>


    <link href="Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.grid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.core.min.js"></script>-->


    <script>
        var app = angular.module("KendoDemos", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.controller("CustomerController", function ($scope) {

            $scope.gridData = [
                { customerId: 1, customerName: 'shikhar1' },
                { customerId: 2, customerName: 'shikhar2' },
                { customerId: 3, customerName: 'shikhar3' },
                { customerId: 4, customerName: 'shikhar4' }


                //{
                //dataSource: "http://localhost:58816/api/Values"
        //             }
            ];

            $scope.gridColumns = [{
                field: "customerId",
                title: "customerId",
                width: "120px"
            }, {
                field: "customerName",
                title: "customerName",
                width: "120px"
            }];

        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have your `CustomerController` nested inside another one?

Comment: o ..thats by mistake....i removed that..still same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all since you are using `kendo-grid`, `k-data-source` and `k-columns` which are directives, you need to add `kendo.directives` as an app dependency

```
var app = angular.module("KendoDemos", ["ngRoute", "kendo.directives"]);
```

Here's a [Working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/cPygYliuKU4k91v3gQK2?p=preview) of a Kendo Grid using your options. Hope this helps